# Clarification regarding net-logo let and error message

Tags: netlogo

I don't understand reporters very well, so I am having trouble creating them. However, I think this one should work. I already set food quality to be random to be a random value from 0-1 using a slider, and based on my understanding you set a variable to be a new local variable using let.

```
to-report food-quality-level
  ifelse food-quality > 0.6
  [let food-value high-quality]
  [let food-value low-quality]
  report food-quality-level
end
```

However, I get the error: nothing low-quality has been defined. How should this be corrected?
Then in the procedures, do I say:

```
ask breed
if food-quality-level [high-quality]
[action]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with this, mostly to do with confusion between variable names, procedure names and variable values. You are (sort of) using 'food-quality-level' as both the procedure name and the variable name, and you are using variable name syntax when you want variable values.

What I have done here is add comments that say what each line actually does (rather than what you intended):

```
; create a procedure named "food-quality-level"
to-report food-quality-level
  ; check if value of variable "food-quality" is more than 0.6    
  ifelse food-quality > 0.6      
  ; (on true) assign the contents of variable "high-quality" to variable "food-value"
  [let food-value high-quality] 
  ; (on false) assign the contents of variable "low-quality" to variable "food-value"
  [let food-value low-quality]
  ; output the value of the variable "food-quality-level" (except it's not a variable)
  report food-quality-level
end
```

What I think you want to do is return some text which categorises whether the variable value is high or low (with 0.6 as the break point). If so, you want something more like this:

```
to-report food-quality-level
  ifelse food-quality > 0.6      
  [let food-value "high-quality"]   ; creates the value as text
  [let food-value "low-quality"]
  report food-value                 ; returns the newly created variable
end
```

A more advanced version of the same thing is:

```
to-report food-quality-level
  report ifelse-value food-quality > 0.6      
  ["high-quality"]
  ["low-quality"]
end
```

Here, I am using `ifelse-value` instead of the `ifelse ... [set ...][set ...]` construction and reporting the output as it is created.

Comment: Thanks! How do I get my turtles to run the reporter and act accordingly? I know this is incorrect, but shouldn't it be: `````to forage
  ask foragers 
  [if food-quality-level ["high quality"]
  face food-x food-y
      fd 1]
end````

Comment: Try out your code and ask a new question if you can't get it to work. But you definitely need an '=' in there